# Install Mono on CentOS 5.5 using Yum

Tags: apache-2.2, mono

I'm trying to install mono on a CentOS 5.5 machine. I assumed I will be using the OpenSUSE packages (i'm not sure thought, there are other options like Debian and Ubuntu). I created a mono.repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d with the content

```
[mono]
name=novell-mono
baseurl=http://origin-download.mono-project.com/download-stable/openSUSE_11.4/
gpgcheck=0
```

Now I;m not sure which package to install using yum, yum install mono-stable does nothing, which package i should get, note that ill be running it on with Apache.

Appreciate the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a link answer would be a bad idea, but since it's within the network, I figure it's OK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510320/install-mono-on-centos5-5-using-yum (third hit on Google for "mono centos", by the way).

Comment: already tried that, but i am getting monotools-addon-server not found

Comment: i think it's yum install mono-complete, but now i get missing dependency error libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9) and other versions of the glibc